# How to Create skeleton script in bash that takes the input from file.JSON(files represent devices)

Tags: bash, shell, apache-kafka

i need to create script in bash that takes the json file as input from a folder. Lets say json file looks like this:

```
{\"mac_address\": null, \"serial_number\": \"A-HCI1\", \"device_type\": \"STORAGE\", \"device_model\": \"NIMBLE DHCI STORAGE\", \"part_number\": \"6790\", \"extra_attributes\": [
{\"attribute_type\": \"ENTITLEMENT_ID\", \"attribute_value\": \"YIZUYYNEYSFO9ghhhgAU\"}
```

and then  CCS quotes the json in the event data field of the Kafka event - A valid kafka event will look like

```
{
    "specversion": "4.0",
    "id": "(i will be using uuid genereator for that",
    "source": "CCS",
    "type": "DEVICE_PROVISION_EVENT",
    "time": "local time",
    "data": "{\"mac_address\": null, \"serial_number\": \"ADL23231\", \"device_type\": \"DHCI_STORAGE\", \"device_model\": \"NIMBLE DHCI STORAGE\", \"part_number\": \"6320\", \"extra_attributes\": [{\"attribute_type\": \"ENTITLEMENT_ID\", \"attribute_value\": \"YIZUYYNEYSFO9ZV0LVAU\"}],\"tag_entities\": [], \"platform_customer_id\": \"a07db108sadasd33325ee95\", \"application_customer_id\": \"31187723dfd32a93178\", \"folder_name\": null}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you flatten the JSON into a single line, you can just input into the kafka console consumer

```
kafka-console-producer.sh --topic foo --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 < data.json
```

But from your previous questions, you should ideally stick with Python or Go based producer scripts rather than shell scripts for flexibility.

Comment: So the CSS quotes the json in the event data filed of the kafka event . If you look on data element on code the json file is inside of data element. So its like structure within structure

Comment: That's fine. It's just a string.

Comment: You cannot "embed" JSON into other JSON files easily within bash. That's why I recommended Python/Go

Comment: how can i do it with go i found this function ```quotedString := strconv.Quote(string(marshaledBytes))``` in go

Comment: scripts suppose take the json file and that generates required kafka event event